# How to show the first 13 cards

Tags: python, string, list, string-function

I am trying 2 different codes on how to print the first 13 cards but i can't seem to know how.

1.
[image]

I need to print only the first 13 cards here but idk how to.

2.[image]

This another code, I am confused on list slicing and how to remove the '' between them

I was able to print the first 13 cards but I am confused why it is [1:91] if I already put "" per string? And I dont know how to remove the ''  between strings and spaces before the parenthesis.

I have to print the first 13 cards (which were C) but I dont know how

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code or error messages.

Comment: In your first snippet, use `i = 0` instead of the first for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use images to upload text.

```
houses = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
ranks = ['A', '2', '3' ... 'Q', 'K']
deck = []

for house in houses:
    for rank in ranks:
        deck.append(f"{rank}-{house}")

for i in range(13):
    print(deck[i])
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new here! But thanks for pointing it out.